# Configuring Camera Raw presets

Tags: adobe-camera-raw

I have a Sony A73 with a 'full-spectrum' sensor filter conversion. There are several ways to use this. For now, I am set up for three:

1. Ordinary visible light
2. false color infrared
3. b&w infrared

I would like to quickly switch Adobe Camera Raw to the appropriate setup. I see that there is a concept of a per-camera default, but I find the UI in in Bridge/Camera Raw confusing; there seem to multiple concepts of 'profile', and further bridge's previews seem to be shown using some default or another in Camera Raw, and I don't know how or if that can be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridge previews are likely JPEGs embedded in raw file.

There is only a single concept of camera profile and it's a DCP profile located somewhere in Adobe's folders which you can override with something you yourself created.

https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/adjust-color-rendering-camera-camera.html

[image]

If you want a preset (combination of Camera Raw parameters) that's another story.

https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/camera-raw-settings.html

[image]